# Console mostra log do javascript muito rápido e não da tempo visualizar saída

Tags: javascript, html, console

Esse é meu código é um formulário simples:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Formulário</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <form name="meu_form">

        <h1>Formulário</h1>

        <p class="nome">
            <label for="nome">Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nomeid" required="required" name="nome" />
        </p>

        <p class="fone">
            <label for="fone">Fone</label>
            <input type="text" id="foneid" name="fone" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="emailid" name="email" />
        </p>
        <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" onclick="enviar()" value="Enviar" />
        </p>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function enviar() {

            var nome = document.getElementById("nomeid");
            var fone = document.getElementById("foneid");
            var email = document.getElementById("emailid");

            if (nome.value != "") {
               console.log('Obrigado sr(a) ' + nome.value +
                 ' os seus dados foram encaminhados com sucesso.\n'
                 +'Seus dados:\n'
                 +'Nome : '+ nome.value
                 +'\nFone '+ fone.value 
                 +'\nEmail '+ email.value);
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Se eu substituir o console pelo alert dá certo, mas quero usar o console.

O problema é que quando eu quero visualizar a saída no console do navegador **Chrome** (não testei em outros) ele é exibida tão rápido que não da tempo ler.

O que devo fazer?

Comment: porque você não sua o alert?

Comment: Você está usando qual navegador?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para manter o console no **Google Chrome** você deve seguir os seguintes passos:

- Aperte **f12** no seu teclado para abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvedor.
- Na aba **Console** existe uma pequena engrenagem do lado direito, clique nela.
- Feito isso, diversas configurações irão aparecer, marque a opção **Preserve log**
- O console já deve estar sendo preservado.

Comment: Valeu grande! Muito interessante , me ajudou bastante!